# Windows 7 Ultimate x64 alternative Programs directory

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I have a PC with multiple hard drives. One is for the Windows installation (C:), one which I would like to use to install ALL programs (D:), and the rest for data (E:, F:, G:, ...). I want to move the 'Programs' folder to the D: drive, or (alternatively) create a new Programs folder on D: which will be the default destination for new programs I install - preferably with the same security features as the original Windows default Programs folder.

My reasons for wanting to do this are as follows:
1) Speed of access to disks (they are separate physical drives - not just separate partitions on a single drive).
2) Ease of reinstallation of my Windows images (images are smaller; less time taken for backups/ restores, less space taken by images). I use imaging software to do this.
3) My Windows drive is too small for all the programs / games / etc. I want to install (it's a 300Gb Velociraptor, with 2 partitions - I have a dual-boot system, XP & Win 7).

I have 2 accounts - Admin (used only for such installations, updates, etc) and a User account (for daily use). Sometimes I will need to run programs as Admin while logged on as User.

Please give me advice on the best way to accomplish this.

Philip B.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft's website this is possible

> The ProgramFilesDir registry value is located in the following
>   registry subkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion You may
>   want to use the ProgramFilesDir registry entry to change the location
>   of the Program Files folder. Additionally, you may want to modify
>   every reference in the registry to point to the new Program Files
>   folder. You may also want to move the contents of the original Program
>   Files folder to the new location. However, we do not test changes to
>   the default location of the Program Files folder. Therefore, we do not
>   recommend or support modifying the ProgramFilesDir registry value to
>   change the default location of the Program Files folder.

But according to them it's also not recommended

> Microsoft does not support changing the location of the Program Files
>   folder by modifying the ProgramFilesDir registry value. If you change
>   the location of the Program Files folder, you may experience problems
>   with some Microsoft programs or with some software updates.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700

See here to find out how it's done
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1328-change-the-default-installation-folder-c-program-files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542100/changing-program-files-default-location-in-windows-7